# Adding archive years to my menu

Tags: menus, archives, dropdown

I'm Wordpress newbie and despite of reading many articles, I'm able to put archive years to my main menu.

Menu contains pages and I need to add an archive.

My current menu:

```
- Home (page)
- About (page)
- News (Category)
- Contact (page)
```

And I need

```
- Home (page)
- About (page)
- News (Category) - link to the newest year (2015)
- - 2015 (not category, just year when posts were added)
- - 2014
- - 2013
- Contact (page)
```

When I removed the last one category from year 2014, this year should disappear from  my navigation.

When I add new post in January 2016, automatically year 2016 will appear in my dropdown, and 'News' will containt direct link to `2016`.

Any idea how to do it?
PS. I really read many articles and see the WP first time (I'm a programmer). I'm able to do it using many ways, but looking for the best one, looking the best wordpress approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please follow below code do add dynamically year wise post under sub menu you want, I have added below code in **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'ravs_add_menu_parent_class' );

function ravs_add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
   //print_r($item);//print each menu item an get your parent menu item-id
   // get your menu item ID use that ID in below code and you can remove this code after getting ID 
  }
  GLOBAL $wpdb;
  $years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );



  foreach($years as $year){
    $link = array (
          'title'            => $year->year,
         // 'title'            =>($year->year == date('Y') ) ?  'News (Category)' : $year->year, // this is how you want to print latest year as "News (Category)" 
          'menu_item_parent' => '13',  // my menu id is 13 ie: ID of menu name test under which years links are displayed 
          'ID'               => '',
          'db_id'            => '',
          'url'              => '/'.$year->year  // to create url of menu item 
      );
    $items[] = (object) $link;
  }
  return $items;    
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**Other Case like you want :**

Just use like below:

`'title' =>($year->year == date('Y') ) ?  'News (Category)' : $year->year,`

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @jas, it overwrites me whole menu to just years taken from posts. Now I see just `2015 - 2014 - 2013`, not other pages... Any idea what I did incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using this code in same way, I have updated image, for me its displaying all other menu items and submenu under test are archives, please provide some details.

Comment: Yes, I copied whole your code to functions.php... I can provide you FTP access if you want to look on it. I don't know what more details I can tell you :-/ Maybe... when I comment the first line, it does nothing (show my current menu without subitems). When I uncomment it, see just years.

Comment: now I tried to find function name from the 1st line, `wpa_remove_menu_item`, but this string is nowhere in my whole website folder... It seems like function name you have somewhere and I haven't... Can be the problem here?

Comment: Please remove that first line and check now with updated answer, I think I copied some extra line from my file while pasting answer here.

Comment: Still nothing, but... when I do `print_r($items)` before `return`, I see my years in object. But not in text nodes in menu... Here is printscreen what I have - http://wp.lbcomputers.cz/wp.png. Item 'Aktuality' has ID 93. So, in object, in `print_r` it seems to be okay, but I dont know why the new items aren't in menu links?

Comment: Can I send you FTP login data to mail, to save your time? :-) If so, please send me your e-mail address to malcharekroman@gmail.com. Then we post here where the problem was

Comment: I sent you email but FYI I tried now in my themes "Twenty Fourteen" and "Twenty Fifteen" functions.php so code is working fine for every theme.